# PostgreSQL UPDATE query issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have devices table like this:

```
traccar=# \d devices;
                                          Table "public.devices"
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |               Default               
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------
 id             | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('devices_id_seq'::regclass)
 name           | character varying(128)      |           | not null | 
 uniqueid       | character varying(128)      |           | not null | 
 lastupdate     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 positionid     | integer                     |           |          | 
 groupid        | integer                     |           |          | 
 attributes     | character varying(4000)     |           |          | 
 phone          | character varying(128)      |           |          | 
 model          | character varying(128)      |           |          | 
 contact        | character varying(512)      |           |          | 
 category       | character varying(128)      |           |          | 
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 driveruniqueid | character varying(50)       |           |          | 
 protocol       | character varying(128)      |           |          | 
 disabled       | boolean                     |           |          | false
Indexes:
    "pk_devices" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uk_device_uniqueid" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (uniqueid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_devices_groupid" FOREIGN KEY (groupid) REFERENCES groups(id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL
Referenced by:
    TABLE "device_attribute" CONSTRAINT "fk_device_attribute_deviceid" FOREIGN KEY (deviceid) REFERENCES devices(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "device_command" CONSTRAINT "fk_device_command_deviceid" FOREIGN KEY (deviceid) REFERENCES devices(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "device_driver" CONSTRAINT "fk_device_driver_deviceid" FOREIGN KEY (deviceid) REFERENCES devices(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "device_geofence" CONSTRAINT "fk_device_geofence_deviceid" FOREIGN KEY (deviceid) REFERENCES devices(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "device_maintenance" CONSTRAINT "fk_device_maintenance_deviceid" FOREIGN KEY (deviceid) REFERENCES devices(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "device_notification" CONSTRAINT "fk_device_notification_deviceid" FOREIGN KEY (deviceid) REFERENCES devices(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "user_device" CONSTRAINT "fk_user_device_deviceid" FOREIGN KEY (deviceid) REFERENCES devices(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

For some reason two very similar `UPDATE` queries vary drastically in execution time. Statistics from `pg_stat_statements`:

```
                    short_query                     | total_time | calls |   mean   | percentage_cpu 
----------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+----------------
 UPDATE devices SET positionId = $1 WHERE id = $2   |  325376.29 | 21053 |    15.46 |          89.70
 UPDATE devices SET lastUpdate = $1 WHERE id = $2   |     471.75 |  6491 |     0.07 |           0.13
```

What could be the issue and how to fix it? I have checked execution plans and they are exactly the same for both queries.

Database version info:

```
PostgreSQL 10.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit
```

Comment: Your table has very wide columns which are generally expensive to update. If you update those two small columns a lot, consider a redesign, moving the big immutable columns to a rarely updated separate 1:1 table. Would also help performance of all those FK constraints. Other than that I cannot spot anything suspicious that might explain the difference. Are you sure the statistics are representative? Some freak values from stalled queries in the past maybe? Did you test both queries and still get factor 200 comparing their performance?

Comment: I have reset statistics twice and still get the save average values. Unfortunately redesigning the table is not an option at this stage. Any other ideas on where to look for a solution? I just want to get reasonable numbers for `positionId` update. I don't understand why it takes so much longer to execute.

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for each might reveal something.

Comment: Was postionid null before the update, while lastupdate wasn't?  The "\d devices" would have shown any triggers.  You didn't leave them off, I hope?

Comment: `pg_stat_statements` doesn't have a `percentage_cpu` field.  How are you defining that?

Comment: Could it by that updates to lastUpdate are always immediately preceded by updates to positionId with the same value of $2, and so find everything in cache waiting for it?